# ANDROID: Weighted Linear List Buttons disappear

Tags: android, xml, button, android-linearlayout, weighted

I have seen many posts about this and have tried many of the solutions but for some reason nothing is working.  I just want the buttons to share equal space... Can you please look at my xml code and see if something is wrong? Thanks!

`<ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollview1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="120">
            <Button android:id="@+id/btn_mission" android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#8D8BB7"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:text="Mission">
            </Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/btn_news" android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#8D8BB7"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:text="News/Events">
            </Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/btn_studentservices"
                android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#8D8BB7" android:layout_weight="20"
                android:text="Student Services">
            </Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/btn_facultyservices"
                android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#8D8BB7" android:layout_weight="20"
                android:text="Faculty Services">
            </Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/btn_staff" android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#8D8BB7"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:text="Staff">
            </Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/btn_library" android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#8D8BB7"
                android:layout_weight="20" android:text="Library">
            </Button>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>`

EDIT: It seems to be something to do with setting the background I removed the background and everything shared equal space except you still must scroll.

Comment: `I just want the buttons to share equal space... `  What does that mean?  Horizontally?  Vertically?  Please clarify what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LinearLayout has a vertical orientation, so instead of `android:layout_width="0dp"` you should use `android:layout_height="0dp"`.

Comment: The are appearing now but is there a way for them to take up the empty space right now they are just listed one after another.

Comment: Try with android:layout_width="fill_parent" for each Button (I'm not sure if it's what you want).

Answer (score 2):

Try removing `android:weightSum="120"` and setting the `android:layout_weight="20"` to `android:layout_weight="1"` on all of the buttons.